# Error: (gcloud.alpha.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Cannot access Google Cloud Functions API in project

Tags: api, cloud, ocr, vision

I'm new using Google's APIs.

I'm following step by step the next tutorial made by Google: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr

I want to deploy a specific function provided by Google (the `processImage` function).

I entered this into the console:

```
gcloud alpha functions deploy ocr-extract --stage-bucket [YOUR_STAGING_BUCKET_NAME] --trigger-bucket [YOUR_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME] --entry-point processImage
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: (gcloud.alpha.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Cannot access Google Cloud Functions API in project
```

Comment: Did you enable cloud functions on cloud.google.com? And, is your account whitelisted for access by Google?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I already enabled the necesary API's and I filled the form for being whitelisted. My questions is, do I have to do something else that does not appear in the tutorial of OCR provided by google.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to be sure, you aren't actually using YOUR_STAGING_BUCKET_NAME in the command? You are replacing that with your real bucket name, right?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it to "stagingbucketlatert" (latert is the name of my proj). BTW I think it is problem of credentials, in that tutorial I am not asked to add credentials wich is weird for me, I think.. I have doubts in just one step of that tutorial and is where I config the conf.json file. I am not pretty sure what is a "YOUR_RESULT_TOPIC_NAME" I just put a name...

Comment: May be it could sound stupid but I am not pretty sure in what moment do I use the file index.js provided by google??  because in that file I saw that they made the requests and permisions.

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same error. It got resolved once I did `gcloud init` in my command prompt terminal. Mentioned command linked my GCP project to the folder where my files were present. After that command mentioned by you worked.

Comment: This works. An alternative is to use `gcloud auth revoke` and then `gcloud auth login` to authenticate the desired account.

Answer (score 2):

You should Initialize the SDK first.

1. run `gcloud init`
2. config your login account and select your project name.

Answer (score 0):

it might be silly but be sure to enable the cloud functions api in your project settings on the gcloud dashboard website.

[image]